# Does my RubyGem repo need the vendor directory?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Currently I am developing a RubyGem. To do so I have some development dependencies declared in the gemspec file.

```
  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.10"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rspec", "~> 3.4"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rspec-its", "~> 1.2"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rdoc", "~> 4.2"
  spec.add_development_dependency "simplecov", "~> 0.11.2"
```

Due to this I have a directory called "vendor" with a directory called "ruby" and a lot of gems in it.

My question is, do I need to push this directory or does a contributing developer get these files when using bundle on the directory (or manually installing the gems)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include a vendor directory in your gem. If you include a Gemfile  pointing to your gemspec, other contributing developers will be just fine using Bundler.

```
# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gemspec
```